# SKSpriteNode subclassing. iOS 8.4 vs 9.x

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, subclass, skspritenode

I've made an app and all along I have been using a custom made subclass with special properties like this

```
class SKSpriteNodeB: SKSpriteNode{

var tempFlag = Bool()
var tempA = CGFloat()
var tempB = CGFloat()
var tempC = CGFloat()    

}
```

and calling like this :

```
   override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for _ in touches {
        let touch: UITouch = touches.first!
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let touchedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(location) as? SKSpriteNodeB
        touchedNode.tempA = 5.0
        touchedNode.tempFlag = false
        //Do something
}}
```

This works well in iOS 9.0 and above but when I tested it in my iPad mini running iOS 8.4 these SKSpriteNodeB's are not responding to touches. I have other nodes that are not SKSpriteNodeB's and are functioning correctly. Some advice would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Did you set the sprite's `userInteractionEnabled` property to `true`? Also, unless you've added child nodes to the sprite, there's no need to check for `nodeAtPoint`, since `touchesBegan` will only be called when the sprite is touched.

Comment: I didnt set it to true but did not explicitly set `userInteractionEnabled` to `false` because I thought it is false by default. Also I think I require `nodeAtPoint` because I have different node types i.e `SKLabelNode` and I have an `if` statement that checks  `touchedNode.name`

Comment: I think I might have solved it. Id have to look into this more but I think it has to do with the zPosition of the node. I did a simple `print(touchedNode.name)` and found out that for some reason in iOS 8.4 when I have a node's `hidden` property set to `true` I am able to still tap on it. I had to increase the `zPosition` of the node to be able to tap on it. Do you have any idea why that is?

Comment: Setting the `hidden` property of a node prevents it from being rendered. The node still interacts with other nodes in the scene and responds to touches. I believe you need to set `userInteractionEnable = true` to allow your sprite subclass to receive touch events.

Comment: Setting `userInteractionEnabled = true` solves it and makes it now tappable. However now I am sometimes able to tap through the node and hit another `SKLabelNode` located below it instead even if it is set as `hidden` and `userInteractionEnabled = true`. I might just give up and have my app be only compatible for 9.0 and above.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I do in situations like this, when I want a node to be "hidden" but still tappable is instead of setting hidden to true, I set alpha to 0.0, and the when I want to "unhide" the node I just increase the alpha of the node.

Comment: Id have to jot this down somewhere. Neat trick! However I dont want other nodes to be tappable. They are just tappable even though they are set to hidden

Comment: In that case, the node you do not want to be tappable just set them to userInteractionEnabled = false.

Comment: Setting a node's `userInteractionEnabled` to `false` doesn't make it un-tappable. It only prevents it from receiving touch events (its `touchBegan` won't be called).